# Inserting multiple records with one click in Telerik mvc grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, grid, telerik

I am working on a Telerik MVC grid. My requirement is to allow a user to insert multiple records into the grid. This should be done on the client side.

After entering several records in the grid, the user will click a button so that all the records are inserted into the database.

Is this possible with Telerik MVC grid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide for doing a batch update from Telerik themselves: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdperformingbatchupdates.html

Here is a demo using automatic operations to allow multi-row editing: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/alleditablecolumns/defaultcs.aspx

Here is another ticket which links to a demo from Telerik doing this type of thing: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/339723-batch-insert.aspx

Bottom line: it can be done, but it isn't super easy and will require quite a bit of custom code.  More than I am able to share here, but the above links (especially the last one) should provide you the resources you need.

Comment: im more interested in doin this using Telerik grid for ASP.NET MVC 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Not supported out-of-the-box from the Telerik MVC grid extensions AFAIK, but it should be possible by making jQuery ajax or web service calls which add items in the source and bind the grid. And I recently heard that they crafted batch client edits/updates for the Q1 2011 release, due in mid March.

Comment: To add to this, you can see that "Batch Editing" is planned for the Q1 2011 release on [Telerik's roadmap](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/whats-new/roadmap.aspx) (hopefully that link came through ;))

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of Telerik MVC Grid supports what's called batch editing directly. [Here is the documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-editing-cell-editing-and-batch-updates.html) on how to use the new feature.